# Make multipage login form work with password managers

Tags: javascript, html, forms, lastpass

I am moving to multipage authentication form with sso and that time one state holds user name then next state holds the password input.
Now Last pass stopped working I've added `autocomple="username"` that gives chrome native suggestions but not all for the site.

I've tried with fake hidden password input but still Last pass doesn't work `opacity` `visibility` `display: none` everything fails. Just one thing i managed to work is making pwd field absolute and with some long left position.

```
<input
    tabIndex="-1"
    type="password"
    style={{ position: 'absolute', left: 99999 }}
/>
```

Is there any better approach to fix this or this will work and won't have any unknown challenges?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: See also: https://hiddedevries.nl/en/blog/2018-01-13-making-password-managers-play-ball-with-your-login-form. It has a workaround for LastPass. In my tests it also works if the password field is moved off-screen (like what you're doing).